# jQuery load() dynamic content with clicks get fired as many times as loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I load content via jQuery load() but for each time I load a given page, the clicks on the pages gets fired multiple times. Why??

**Se the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUZ3L/ph3tH/2/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're adding the click event multiple times.

Every time your code runs, the click function is re-defined. When a click is redefined it won't replace the previous one, but instead will be added to the stack to be executed each time the "click" event occurs. This is applied to all events in jQuery.

As you are loading via AJAX the vars and events in the document are still persisted. Meaning that you are just adding layer on top of layer of function calls to be executed each time you run your ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Simply put your click hander outsie of `load`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadContent() {
        $(".ajaxContainer").load("http://fiddle.jshell.net/ #actions", function() {
            alert("Done");                
        });
    }

    $(".load").click(loadContent);
    loadContent();
});​
```

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph3tH/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Each time you load content, you execute this line:

```
$(".load").click(loadContent);
```

which adds a new event handler to the list of event handlers to execute whenever `.load` is clicked. You execute your function three times, now you have three identical handlers all triggering for each click.

Comment: If I just unbind("click") all the links before each load, it should be fine??

Comment: Why would you rebind it in the first place? Just bind it once. You can see in other answers how it's normally done.

Answer (score 1):

because you are calling the function 2 times, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadContent() {
        $(".ajaxContainer").load("http://fiddle.jshell.net/ #actions", function() {
            alert("Done");
        });
    }
    loadContent();
    $(".load").click(loadContent);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ph3tH/4/

Comment: This is just an example. I have so many links in so many pages. For organizing I have the click events inside the call function. Is there another way??

Comment: @KennethB this makes your function to be called two times, there are better ways for organizing, use click handlers after defining the function.